# Locking an iPhone if button is broken?

Tags: iphone, hardware

My friend's iPhone's sleep/wake button no longer works. Is there any way to turn off the screen besides setting up auto-lock and waiting a few minutes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It appears that if you go into **Settings > General > Accessibility** and enable **Assistive Touch**, a new transparent button appears on your iPhone. This button can be accessed all the time. It is overlayed over anything appearing on your phone. If you tap it, and then tap **Device**, one of the options is **Lock Screen**.

Instead of having the icon always be visible, you can go to the **Triple-click Home** setting under the Accessibility page and choose AssistiveTouch. This way you can easily show or hide the button with a triple-click of the home button!

Answer (score 4):

1. Download and install the [Find My iPhone](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/find-my-iphone/id376101648?mt=8) app.
2. When you want to lock the screen, launch the app, find your own iPhone.
3. Remote Lock your own iPhone

[image]

ps - I never said it was an *elegant* solution :-) The OP asked "Is there ***any way***" [emphasis added]. This works, I tested it myself.

Comment: Clever usage of Find my iPhone! Just watch out not to tap the button to it's right ;)

Comment: The good news is that it will prompt you to confirm whichever choice you make :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you go to:

1. Settings
2. General
3. Accessibility
4. Assistive Touch

It provides a transparent circle icon in which you can do many things, such as locking the screen, snapshots, home button, and much more! It worked great for me (my lock button broke as well).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This appears to be the same as the one that OP posted and accepted. Is there something that you could edit in that would make differ from his?

Answer (score 2):

if your phone is jailbroken, you can download and install activator which allows you to change any other buttons to the lock button. You can also set pressing the home button twice to lock or other finger gestures to lock too. Mine got jammed and I used the volume up button to lock because the assistive button is really painful to use I have to click 3-4 times before locking my phone.

Comment: Can you add a download link for the app you mentioned?